# Нелинейное изменение передаваемых в ОС координат конкретного устройства

Tags: android, windows, unix, драйвер, мышь

работаем над одним проектом, суть которого, в контексте данного вопрос не важна, но важно, что в этом проекте задействована работа с сенсорной панелью. И именно по вопросу взаимодействия с ней мы зашли в тупик.

**Постановка задачи примерно следующая:** перехват конкретной мыши (в нашем случае сенсорная панель, которая определяется, как мышь) в ОС для нелинейного изменения передаваемых в ОС координат, т.е. реализации функции калибровки искаженного изображения. При этом, важно, чтобы другие устройства, в частности, мышь, должны работать в обычном режиме.

Пробовали копать в сторону 33 прерывания - всё что нашли несколько устарело и подходит скорее для изменения передаваемых координат, но не для идентификации нужного нам устройства (сенсорной панели), да и только под DOS. По крайней мере, насколько мы это смогли понять, возможно это и ошибочное мнение, поправьте, если это так.

Желательно обойтись без совсем низкоуровневого программирования, но если его не избежать (что мы предполагаем), то подойдёт и пути через эти дебри.

Очень бы хотелось бы получить хотя бы какие-то хлебные крошки - в какую сторону копать, так как на данный момент не осталось совсем никаких мыслей.
Будем очень благодарны :)

UPD1:
Проект заточен под семейства Window (начиная с 7) и Unix системы, в перспективе - Android. Но пока что идёт разработка под Windows и в тупик забрели именно там. Но за помощь с вектором движения на них (Unix и Android) тоже будем благодарны, так как, подозреваю, там некоторые проблемы будут схожи.

UPD2:
Необходимость имеется именно в изменении координат, при работе с с нашей программой, но если они будут в пределах всей системы - это не критично.

Answer (score 0):

1) Поставить хук на мышь или GETMESSAGE и в функции перехвата заменить данные. Не уверен, что данные можно подменить, т.к. использовал только для логирования. Возможно, придётся вызывать mouse_event с новыми координатами.

2) Использовать [библиотеку-перехватчик](http://www.oblita.com/interception.html)